# Calculating a string similarity ratio for certain pairs of a set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv, with first row as header, that looks like this:

```
player,career
a,"arsenal, arsenal fc, arsnal fc, barcelona, chelsea"
b,"barcelona, barcelona fc, arsenal, liverpool, liverpol"
c,"newcastle fc, stoke city"
d,"chelsea, everton"
```

The column career is an ordered set of teams in the career of a (soccer) player. If the same team appears more than once that is because the player spent more than one season there. For instance, player D was at Chelsea and then moved to Everton. Player A spent three seasons at Arsenal before going to Barcelona.

I want to identify **when a player moves** to a new team (which is a challenge because the names of the teams are not standardized). In order to do this, I calculate a similarity ratio between the strings (I am using difflib.SequenceMatcher). The basic idea is that I look backwards and compare the focal team to the past teams. I also look forward and compare the focal team to the future teams.

For example, for player A and the element '**arsnal fc**' (third in the set) I calculate the similarity ratio for the pairs (2,1) and (2,0), get the max and the min (*backward similarity*). Then I calculate the ratio for the pairs (2,3) and (2,4) and get the max and the min (*forward similarity*).

Below I show the script that creates a dictionary that contains the max value of the backward similarity ratio (I am able to tweak `dictpre_max` function in order to get the other measures I need).

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
import difflib
import re
from itertools import *
from decimal import Decimal

def split_it(x):
    return re.findall('\w+', x)

def apply_sm(c1, c2): 
    return round(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, c1, c2).ratio(),4)

def dictpre_max(x):

    dictpre = {}

    career = x.split(',')

    for index,team in enumerate(career):
        if index == 0:
            a = index
        else:
            for preorder in range(0,index+1):
                if preorder != index:
                    dictpre[index,preorder] = apply_sm(career[index],career[preorder])

    dictpremax = {}

    for index,team in enumerate(career):
        total = []

        for preorder in range(0,index+1):
            if preorder != index:
                a = [dictpre[(index,preorder)]]
                total = total + a

        if len(total)>0:

            dictpremax[index]=max(total)

    return dictpremax

filenameinput = 'careers.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filenameinput)

df['maxpre'] = df['career'].apply(dictpre_max)

print(df)
```

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way (or more pythonic) of achieving this. I am still not able to calculate all the measures with the same function because I get an error

> (ValueError: too many values to unpack)

when I try to assign the values to more than one df column at once. However, I want to first try to see if there is a cleaner way of writing the `dictpre_max` function.